# PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT error on Android 12

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

In my app I am planing to set up a alarm on each day at a specific time . For that I am using Alarm Manager (See Code below) this is working fine on android devices below 12 but not on 12 and above

Error on Firebase Crashlyics

> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of
> FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a
> PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use
> FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being
> mutable

[Google Crashlytic Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tCGy.png)

This is my Code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Calendar cur = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (cur.after(calendar)) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }



    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mCon, DailyReminder.class);
    int ALARM1_ID = 10000;

        PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCon, ALARM1_ID, myIntent, PendingIntentFLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mCon.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

I went through the net and show following solution

```
  PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCon, ALARM1_ID, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    } else {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCon, ALARM1_ID, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

Can anyone please explain me the difference between PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE.

If I call this method on every time user start the app , Is it ok ? Will it create or update the exisitng alarm?

Thank you

Comment: You can set both flags.

Answer (score 3):

From `Android12` onwards, We need to set the mutability for each use of pending intent

If we consider our app’s min support version is 23, then we can set either immutable or mutable flag to our pending intents objects.

check this solution mentioned in [medium blog's](https://medium.com/native-mobile-bits/lets-use-android-12-migration-of-our-android-apps-to-android12-api-31-af329b6829d0) Step 4.

[image: solution image]

Comment: Thank you very much , What is the difference between Mutable and immutable ?

Comment: @SupunAyeshmantha you can get more details on flag from here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/all-about-pendingintents-748c8eb8619

Answer (score 0):

Must be use `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` or `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` in Android 12 or above.

[Click for more info](https://www.flybuy.com/android-12-pendingintent-mutability-and-geofences)

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCon, ALARM1_ID, myIntent, PendingIntentFLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
```

if still crashing or not working your code so use this dependency, i think it's work for you. add this code in `build.gradle` (:app) file.

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
// required to avoid crash on Android 12 API 31
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
```