# Pending Intent > Flag_Immutable Android 12 Still getting errors

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent, android-12

Here is my Code For the Alarm to be set

```
public void setAlarm(int hr ,int min) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Calendar cur = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (cur.after(calendar)) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mCon, DailyReminder.class);
    int ALARM1_ID = 10000;


    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
       pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCon, ALARM1_ID, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    } else {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCon, ALARM1_ID, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mCon.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

}
```

I did the changes mentioned in this [Stackoverfolw question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73849561/pendingintent-flag-update-current-error-on-android-12) to the above code .

Here is the Broadcast Receiver I used in this

```
public class DailyReminder extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context mCon, Intent intent) {
   BirthdayNotification(mCon,intent);
}
```

private void BirthdayNotification(Context mCon, Intent intent) {

Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCon.getApplicationContext(), "Birthday Notify");
    Intent i2 = new Intent(mCon.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCon, 2, i2, 0);

    DateData dateData=new DateData().getTimeNow();
    ArrayList<DoctorData> Birthday_List=new DataLoader(mCon).getFilteredDoctorData(dateData);

    if(Birthday_List.size()>0){
        //calls planned
        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Birthday's");
        for(DoctorData item :Birthday_List){
            inboxStyle.addLine(item.getName()+"-"+item.getLocation());
        }
        inboxStyle.setSummaryText("Total Birthday's :"+Birthday_List.size());
        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent2);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Doctor Birthday's today");
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        mBuilder.setContentText("See birthday's");
        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) mCon.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            String channelId = "Birthday Channel";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId,
                    "Birthday Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            mBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(2, mBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

}

When I run the above code , the following error shows up again. can anyone help on this?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is little bit mistake,

Use both `PendingIntent Flags` like this example, `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE`

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73849561/pendingintent-flag-update-current-error-on-android-12/73851903#73851903)

in your code change in `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`

```
pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCon, ALARM1_ID, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
```

also change in `PendingIntent.getActivity()`

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCon, 2, i2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
```

Comment: Thanks, Do I need to use check Build verison and apply this? or simply add this?

Comment: No, just change your code.